# DbSet to return multiple entries

Tags: entity-framework, dbset

To return a single entry I use DbSet.SingleOrDefault(l => l.UserName == userName). There must be an equivilent that will return a list of items (assuming there is more than 1). But I can't find it.

What's the Linq call on a DbSet to get a list of matching items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_context.YourEntity.Where(condition).ToList()
```